# C# Custom Event not working, does someone have a suggestion?

Tags: c#, events, console, delegates

I'm currently trying to understand events in C # by writing my own custom event. My goal is to trigger an event after the user enters something into the console. if the string equals to "--start" something should happen. I am currently not reaching my breakpoint in the constructor of my custom event. I hope you can help me.

here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Welcome to the BlackJack Console Game!{Environment.NewLine}" );
        Console.WriteLine($"You get 500 Credits. The minimal Bet is 10 and the maximal 50!{Environment.NewLine}");
        Console.WriteLine($"You can check your Creditcount with --credits{Environment.NewLine}");
        Console.WriteLine($"To Start the Game write --start in the command line{Environment.NewLine}");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        Game game = new Game();
        game.UserInput = userInput;
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public event EventHandler<UserInputEvent> UserWritedInput;

    private string _userInput;

    public string UserInput
    {
        get { return _userInput; }
        set
        {
            _userInput = value;
            OnUserWritedInput();
        }
    }

    public void OnUserWritedInput()
    {
        UserWritedInput?.Invoke(this, new UserInputEvent(_userInput));
    }
}

public class UserInputEvent : EventArgs
{
    private string _userInput;
    public UserInputEvent(string userInput)
    {
        this._userInput = userInput;

        if (_userInput.Equals("--start"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("game started!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't subscribed to the event:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Welcome to the BlackJack Console Game!{Environment.NewLine}" );
        Console.WriteLine($"You get 500 Credits. The minimal Bet is 10 and the maximal 50!{Environment.NewLine}");
        Console.WriteLine($"You can check your Creditcount with --credits{Environment.NewLine}");
        Console.WriteLine($"To Start the Game write --start in the command line{Environment.NewLine}");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        Game game = new Game();
        game.UserWritedInput += OnUserWritedInput;
        game.UserInput = userInput;
    }

    private void OnUserWritedInput(object sender, UserInputEvent args)
    {
        if (args.UserInput.Equals("--start"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("game started!");
        }
    }
}

public class UserInputEvent : EventArgs
{
    public string UserInput {get;}
    public UserInputEvent(string userInput)
    {
         UserInput = userInput;
    }
}
```